# Simple network protocol to send large dict/JSON messages between python nodes

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, tcp, twisted

I am building a Python 3.6 application which distributes specific jobs between available nodes over network. There is one server which builds jobs. Clients connect to the server and are assigned a job, which they return as finished after computation completes.

A job consists of a dict object with instructions, which can get kind of large (> 65536 bytes, probably < 30 MB).

In my first attempt I used the Twisted library to exchange messages via a basic Protocol derived from `twisted.internet.protocol`. When sending a serialized object using `self.transport.write()` and receiving it on the other hand over the callback function `dataReceived()` only 65536 bytes are received. Probably that's the buffer size.

Is there a "simple" protocol which allows me to exchange larger messages between a server and multiple clients in Python 3.6, without adding too much coding overhead?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Take a look to client server api

Comment: HTTP? There are literally dozens of Python framework available to do that for you.

Comment: or use python socket.

Comment: HTTP does not seem to be a good fit, because of its stateless nature. TCP sockets are stream-oriented and not message-oriented, so I would have to implement a custom application level protocol on top.

Comment: HTTP seems like a great fit.  HTTP *is* message-oriented.  The messages are called "requests" or "responses".

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used websockets. It works like a charm, even for large messages.